# redirect one page to another with data in delay 5 seconds+ Spring

Tags: spring, jsp, spring-mvc, spring-data

I am new to Spring.

I have a submit button, when I click on that,

> 1. One intermediate page should be displayed for 5 seconds
> 2. Then display the actual page with data.

Please guide me on how to achieve it.If possible, any sample code would be great. I am currently using Spring 4.3 version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Ravi This can be achieved with the combination of jquery and bootstrap dialog.

**Approach will be like this:**

1)Call an ajax function on Submit of your form.

2)in response show data in bootstrap dialog where u can show data for 5 seconds by using [`setTimeout(function(){ alert("wait till data arrives"); }, 3000);`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_settimeout.asp) Function

3)and than  at last again hit action using 2nd ajax hit or simply open URL by `window.location.href="/admin/realpage"`

This way u can proceed.